# User activation email markdown not (correctly) parsed, no link etc

Tags: users, emails, registration, activation

Our User registration is not working correct anymore.

This is how the Email content part looks after registering a new public user:

```
Hallo craft_user.friendlyName,
danke für das Einrichten eines Benutzerkontos auf craft_siteName. Um 
Ihr Konto zu aktivieren, klicken Sie bitte auf den folgenden Link:

craft_link

Wenn Sie diese Email nicht erwartet haben, ignorieren Sie sie 
bitte einfach.
```

The markers are not parsed at all. The same result occurs, if I send a second activation mail via the CP.
It does already work. We started with Craft 2.3 and did all updates to 2.6. I have no idea when and why this happens.

This is the part of the (original) `/app/translations/de.php`:

```
'account_activation_body' => 'Hallo {{user.friendlyName}},

danke für das Einrichten eines Benutzerkontos auf {{siteName}}. Um 
Ihr Konto zu aktivieren, klicken Sie bitte auf den folgenden Link:

{{link}}

Wenn Sie diese E-Mail nicht erwartet haben, ignorieren Sie sie 
bitte einfach.',
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found the Email "Message" settings where the wrong markers where ("craft_link" instead of "link" etc.) located.

Comment: You're probably going to be better off posting a new 2nd question instead of tacking a question onto the answer to the 1st.